# UICollectionView Items Data distorts after scrolling in Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to implement a chat screen using UICollectionView and data is displayed as expected. However when I try to scroll it a few times my data gets distorted as explained in the screenshots. Can anyone suggest what's going wrong and how to solve it? Thanks!

First it shows:

[image: screenshot at start]

After scrolling a few times it shows:

[image: screenshot after scrolling a bit]

Code of all the methods related to UICollectionView I'm using:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let count = chatCategoriesArray.messages.count
    if count != 0 {
        return count
    }
    return 0
}

var allCellsHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatLogMessageCell
    cell.messageTextView.text = chatCategoriesArray.messages[indexPath.item]
    let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: chatCategoriesArray.messages[indexPath.item]).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)

    if chatCategoriesArray.senderIds[indexPath.item] == "s_\(self.studentInstance.tutorIdFound)"{
        cell.profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "three.png")
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.messageTextView.frame = CGRect(x: 48 + 8, y:0, width: estimatedFrame.width + 16, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
        cell.textBubbleView.frame = CGRect(x: 48, y: 0, width: estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 8, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
        self.currentCellWidth = Double(estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 8)
        cell.textBubbleView.backgroundColor = .white
        cell.addSubview(cell.profileImageView)
        cell.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-8-[v0(30)]", views: cell.profileImageView)
        cell.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(30)]|", views: cell.profileImageView)
    }
    else{
        cell.profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "two.png")
        cell.textBubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 28, g:168, b:261)
        cell.messageTextView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 16 - 46, y:0, width: estimatedFrame.width + 16, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
        cell.messageTextView.textColor = .white
        cell.textBubbleView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 16 - 8 - 46, y: 0, width: estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 8, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
        self.currentCellWidth = Double(estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 8)
        cell.addSubview(cell.profileImageView)
        cell.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:[v0(30)]-8-|", views: cell.profileImageView)
        cell.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(30)]|", views: cell.profileImageView)
    }
    allCellsHeight += cell.frame.height
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    if allCellsHeight < (collectionView.frame.height){
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: view.frame.height - allCellsHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    else {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: chatCategoriesArray.messages[indexPath.item]).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
}
```

Comment: You should not be adding views & constraints in `cellForItemAt` unless you first remove the ones there you have added before (cells are reused!). Your `allCellsHeight` won't work this way. `cellForItemAt` will be called several times for each cell and `cell.frame.height` won't even be correct during this call.

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan your suggestion really worked for me, how can I mark your suggestion as answer? ^_^

Comment: I will convert it to an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collection cells are reused. That means that when you scroll up/down, the cells that become invisible are removed from hierarchy and queued for reusing. Then the collection view calls `cellForItem:` again for the items that become visible. `dequeueReusableCell` does not always create a new instance. Usually it will only return a cell that has become invisible for you to setup it again with new data.

If you add views/constraints during setup, you have to make sure to remove the ones you have added previously, otherwise the cell will have duplicate views and conflicting constraints.

Also note that `allCellsHeight` cannot work like this. `cell.frame.height` won't be correct immediately after setup (before actual layout) and since the method can be called several times for the same item, you cannot just add to a global variable. You should rather use `collectionView.contentSize.height` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Yup needed to .removeFromSuperview() items before adding them.

Answer (score 0):

This is classic reusable cell trouble. This happens cause collection view reuse your receiver cells setting to create sender message box.

I will suggest you to use two different cell for sender and receiver. With constraint set on first load. This will have a positive impact on performance as well.

Check following image to understand how to use 2 cell.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain more on how I could use two different cells in one collectionView.